# React, return generic component

Tags: reactjs

I have code (not mine) with a test where it test this:

```
// loading is some prop
if (loading) {
  return <Text testID='loading'>loading</Text>;
}
```

I want to do a similar test with that part but insted using a `<Text>` component (which is a React Native component) I just simple want to return a "generic component".

How can I do it? I was expecting something like:

```
return (<React.Fragment prop={loading}></React.Fragment)
```

But I have trouble by passing the `loading` value as a prop. I have to test that `loading` prop is present in this generic component.

Comment: I have a test for React Native where simply expecting that some prop (like `loading`) is true on a component called <Text>, but instead using a predefined component, with `return <Text testID='loading>hi</Text>` I want to return a React component, anyone, a generic component that constains like `return <SomeComponent testID='loading>` in that way I could do that test always, not just for <Text> component

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass props to a React fragment, it is mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Does a `View` not work for your use-case?

```
  if (loading) {
      return <View testID='loading'>loading</View>;
  }
```

Comment: `<div>` doesn't work on `React-native` I'm looking for a way to create a "generic" component. Maybe with `React.Component` but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Try `<View>` if you are using React-native.

Comment: That won't work on web. I'm creating a library for both React native and Reactjs, it's a HOC that add some props to a component, any component

Comment: Does the existing `<Test>` component function across React-native and Reactjs as you expect? If so, why not create a HOC as the generic component and have it use the same source as `<Test>`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could use any standard HTML element, so for generic ones, I don't think there's anything better than `<div />` and `<span />`....

```
// loading is some prop
if (loading) {
  return <span testID='loading'>loading</span>;
}
```